# Different behavior of strings and symbols?

Tags: ruby

I was learning ruby recently from [koans](http://www.koans.heroku.com/en) and i noticed one thing about symbols and string objects. When i assigned two different variables same symbols, i found that the object_id's were same.

```
2.1.1 :017 > symbol1 = :a
 => :a 
2.1.1 :018 > symbol2 = :a
 => :a 
2.1.1 :019 > symbol1.object_id
 => 361768 
2.1.1 :020 > symbol2.object_id
 => 361768
```

Now seeing this i thought that it should be true strings and integers too. But when i did same with strings the object id's ended up being different.

```
2.1.1 :021 > string1 = "test"
 => "test" 
2.1.1 :022 > string2 = "test"
 => "test" 
2.1.1 :023 > string1.object_id
 => 13977640 
2.1.1 :024 > string2.object_id
 => 13932280
```

Why is the behavior of symbols and strings different?

Comment: Take a look at this http://www.reactive.io/tips/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings/ - Ruby will reuse symbols, but not strings.

Comment: This is how the symbols are designed. Learn [here](http://rubyforadmins.com/strings-and-symbols#instances-and-reference)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can think of symbols as self-referential interned strings - that is, only one copy of a given symbol will ever exist. This is also true of some objects like Fixnum instances, booleans, or nil, as well. They are not garbage collected, are not duplicable, and are not mutable.

Strings, on the other hand, are garbage collected, are duplicable, and are mutable. Every time you declare a string, a new object is allocated.